# couldn't understand path error while importing schema on ADF datapipeline

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, data-pipeline

I am trying to create a data pipeline in ADF. Where I am creating a **copy activity** to extract data from a **REST API** and store it in azure SQL database.

*The REST API I am trying to extract have column names and values in different arrays. Following is a sample of how the API looks like.*

```
{
  "dataset": {
    "id": num_id,
    "dataset_code": "CodeX",
    "database_code": "BSE",
    "name": "copmany",
    "description": "company description",
    "refreshed_at": "2023-09-01 14:25:40 UTC",
    "newest_available_date": "2020-03-20",
    "oldest_available_date": "2010-03-18",
    "column_names": [
      "Date",
      "Open",
      "High",
      "Low",
      "Close",
    ],
    "frequency": "daily",
    "type": "Time Series",
    "premium": false,
    "limit": null,
    "transform": null,
    "column_index": null,
    "start_date": "2010-03-18",
    "end_date": "2020-03-20",
    "data": [
      [
        "2020-03-20",
        4.5,
        4.7,
        4.45,
        4.48
      ],
      [
        "2020-03-19",
        4.55,
        4.67,
        4.15,
        4.5
      ]
    ],
    "collapse": null,
    "order": null,
    "database_id": 3287
  }
}
```

When I click on import schema it gives me all the data including dataset descriptions. following is a snapshot of the same.[snapshot of the imported schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5idt.png)

So in collection refference I selected the "$['dataset']['data']" option to only get the values. But I am getting an import schema error saying "Failed" with description "couldn't understand path 0"

EDIT:

I want the output to be save into my azuresql sink to look like follows
Date        Open    Close   High    Low
2020-03-20  4.5     4.7     4.45    4.48
2020-03-19  4.55    4.67    4.15    4.5

And the desired schema is

Date  type: date
Open  type: decimal
Close type: decimal
High  type: decimal
Low   type: decimal

Have attached a snapshot of the error msg I am getting while importing schema.
[snapshot of the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGCqt.png)

Edit 2: -Here is the snapshot of the projection.
[image of the projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNVcT.png)

Comment: can you add the error and expected schema and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Looking at the data you provided first of all the data array has a nested array and has only single value not objects. because of it when you are trying to import schema you are getting this error as `couldn't understand path 0`**

To resolve this, you need to use the Data flow activity where you can flatten this dataset object flatten the array according to your requirement.

**Check below steps:**

- First you need to add the source in your data flow activity
- Take the flatten activity and select the `Unroll By` and `Unroot by` as **dataset.data** and map the column as below.
  [image]
  It will give you an Array of data as below:
  [image]
- After this Take derived column transformation to transform the Array to individual values.
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I created a linked service for REST API and another for Azure SQL database. Then created a dataset of type rest and Azure SQL database for above mentioned linked services. Then created a dataflow taking the rest API dataset as the source.  Then I selected request method as "GET". When in projection I click on "Import Projection" it gives me 2 columns. 1) Body (Type {} Complex) 2) headers(Type map). The 1st column has a drop-down ( or nested column) "_courupted_data (Type string). Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: can you add image of your projection? to get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy activity , you can rather use Flatten transformation in mapping dataflow where you have to choose the array column to unroll by which will give you the data in tabular format after flattening it. Here is more details about flatten transformation in mapping dataflow: [Flatten transformation in map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten)

Issue with using collection reference is that it only allows flattening of single array , here in your example you need to flatten 2 arrays: column_names and data.

In dataflow , you can create branches of source and add two flatten transformations and then create common key using surrogate key transformation and then join them using join transformation with the help of common column.

Hope it helps.